# Executing .bat file

Tags: 11.04, installation, command-line

I have a `setup.bat` file which install some applications and i want to execute it.

This is content of *.bat* file :

```
@echo off
cls
Rip_7z.exe x Rip0.7z
cls
del Rip0.7z
cls
Rip_7z.exe x Rip1.7z
cls
del Rip1.7z
```

I think the **Rip_7z.exe** file extracts the **Rip0.7z** and **Rip1.7z** files and builds the app.

How can I do this in the Ubuntu 11.04 Terminal?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can run DOS batch file through `wineconsole`:

```
$ cat ~/.wine/drive_c/file.bat
@echo off
echo Working
pause
$ wineconsole 'C:\file.bat'
```

You get a new windows similar to this

[image]

Also, you can enter an interactive DOS prompt with

```
wineconsole cmd
```

You will get:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You have to run it through cmd eg.:
`wine cmd /c setup.bat`

Comment: This is the single thing that works in the text mode (servers, ssh, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, Wine won't touch batch files.

Why do you have to do it in a terminal? Just open the directory with naultilus, right click the `.7z` files and extract. But if you want to do it the hard way, the appriximate conversion of that script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

7za x RipForGames{0,1}.7z # might want e instead of x
#rm RipForGames{0,1}.7z # commented out in case you want to keep them.
```

A protip for next time: Try not to announce you're downloading pirated material, in a public forum. It might come back to bite you in the arse one day.

Comment: Wine handles batch just fine, downvoted. (Refer to the other two answers)

Answer (score -2):

```
#! /bin/bash

wine RipForGames_7z.exe x RipForGames0.7z
rm RipForGames0.7z
wine RipForGames_7z.exe x RipForGames1.7z
rm RipForGames1.7z
```

Save this as *setup* an run it by typing `bash setup`, and then hitting enter.