# CMD.exe Emulator in Ubuntu to run .cmd/.bat file

Tags: emulation, batch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing .bat file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54266/executing-bat-file)

The title says it all.

I need to create batch files and run and test them. I dont have any Windows machine. If there was any `cmd.exe` emulator in Ubuntu I would have worked on it.

So do you know emulator that can run `.bat`/`.cmd` files?

I know I can use *vmware*, *virtualbox-ose*. But to use it I need existing Windows which I dont have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install Wine and you can run:

```
wine cmd /c mybatch.bat
```

Comment: Wow!! I didn't know `cmd` is  somewhere in wines path

Comment: There's an `explorer` too. They've ported quite a lot of the core stuff.