# Change multiple filenames by replacing a character

Tags: command-line

I have multiple files named like `that : screenshot 13:25.png`
Windows struggle to open these files probably because of the ":".

How can I replace it?

Comment: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved? This will greatly help other users.

Answer (score 57):

In a terminal, `cd` into the right directory and then run this.

```
rename 's/\:/-/g' *.png -vn
```

This will *preview* the renaming. It should replace `:` with `-`.

If that looks right, remove the `n` from the end and then it will do the actual renaming.

**Note**: Ubuntu versions above 17.04 don't ship with `rename`, but it's still available in the default repositories, so use `sudo apt install rename` to obtain it

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I tried and I have this problem: Substitution pattern not terminated at (eval 1) line 1.

Comment: @user236152 Sorry, I went a bit mad with the escaping backslashes (was on autopilot!). Removed a couple and it should be valid now.

Comment: Perhaps a simple **Nautilus Script** that replaces all such characters that might cause problems in other platforms (running on all selected files) could be useful for "multiplatform" people.

Comment: I did rename 's/:/-/g' *.png and it works, thanks !!

Comment: Why put -v at the end ?

Comment: Why use it? It shows you what it's doing (makes it easier to reverse if you make a mistake). Why at the end? Just so you can remove it (or the `n`) easily.

Comment: can you explain why is there `/g` at the end

Comment: @nightcrawler Yeah, that's the global switch. It means it'll keep matching and replacing the whole things until it hits the end of the string. Without it, it would only match and replace the first instance of `:`.

Comment: @Oli thnx for replying, however lets say I want to substitute multiple group of strings with multiple groups of strings e.g `:` with `-`, `%28` with ` ` (space), `%29` with `` (remove it) what would be the *perlexpr* ..I can substitute multiple string groups with a single string group like `s/\:|%28|%29/ /g` ..all will be replace with space but how do I pair them

Comment: @nightcrawler You should be able to chain completely separate replacements: `rename 's/\:/-/g; s/%28/ /g; s/%29//g' ...`

Answer (score 15):

Here's a pure bash solution:

```
for i in *:*; do
    mv -- "$i" "${i//:/_}"
done
```

The `${var//pattern/replacement}` format will replace all occurrences of `pattern` with `replacement` in the variable `$var`. For more information on bash's string maipulation capabilities, see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

If you want to do this for multiple characters, you could simply place them in a character class. So, for example, to replace all of `;`,`:`,`=`,`+`,`%`,`,` with underscores, you could do:

```
$ ls 
1foo:bar  2foo:bar:baz  3foo;bar  4foo=bar  5foo%bar  6foo,bar  7foo+bar
$ for i in *; do mv -- "$i" "${i//[:;=%,+]/_}"; done
$ ls
1foo_bar  2foo_bar_baz  3foo_bar  4foo_bar  5foo_bar  6foo_bar  7foo_bar
```

Basically, the idea is that `[ ]` means `any of the characters listed`. So, by placing all of the characters you want to replace in the character class, all of them are dealt with at once.

The `--` after `mv` signifies the end of options and is needed so that this will work even for file names beginning with `-` which otherwise would have been treated as options passed to `mv`.

---

For the specific characters you asked for, things are a bit more complex because [some of them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15783701/1081936) need to be [escaped](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html) (I am ignoring the `/` since *nix doesn't allow it in file names any more than Windows does so that won't be an issue):

```
$ ls
1foo<bar  2foo>bar  3foo:bar  4foo\bar  5foo|bar  6foo*bar  7foo?bar  8foo"bar  9foo'bar
$ for i in *; do mv -- "$i" "${i//[<>:\\|*\'\"?]/_}"; done
$ ls
1foo_bar  2foo_bar  3foo_bar  4foo_bar  5foo_bar  6foo_bar  7foo_bar  8foo_bar  9foo_bar
```

Note that I escaped the `\`,`'` and `"` by adding a `\` in front of each.

Comment: Can this be enhanced to replace several individual characters (e.g. all those that are not acceptable by Windows) with others?

Comment: @Sadi see updated answer.

Comment: Basically there are nine: "< > : " / \ | ? *"

Comment: @Sadi see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this could help create a **Nautilus Script** that makes names of selected file(s) compatible with Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a GUI, install pyrenamer:

```
sudo apt-get install pyrenamer
```

Then run it:

```
pyrenamer
```

It has dozens of options for patterns and renaming formats.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer **GUI** but as a Nautilus Extension, i.e. **Nautilus Actions Extra**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions-extra
nautilus -q
```

(See [www.webupd8.org/2011/12/nautilus-actions-extra-pack-of-useful.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/nautilus-actions-extra-pack-of-useful.html))

Then when you select files to be renamed and click Rename from the context menu, you are offered many options for renaming files.

Answer (score 0):

The `renameutils` package has a handy program called `qmv` which provides interactive batch renaming. You run it on a directory or a list of files, and it generates a temporary text file containing their file names, and starts your favourite editor. When you exit the editor, any file names you changed are renamed accordingly. `qmv` turns a batch rename problem into a text editing problem.

In this case, you can use `qmv -f do *:*` to edit the names of all the files containing a colon, and then the `:%s/:/_/g` command in Vim (or a corresponding search-and-replace in whatever editor you use).

The `-f do` option sets the format of the text file to have the destination file-name only, which makes the search-and-replace simpler. The default format has two copies of the file name on each line, and you edit only the second one. That allows it to do the right thing if you've deleted or reordered lines in the file, but it's not always the easiest. There are other formats too.

With `qmv`, you can instead choose to pipe the generated file through a command of your choice, such as `sed`, if you don't want the interactive capability.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a **Nautilus Script** that replaces (all?) Windows-incompatible characters with  a hyphen in all selected file names (based on the answer by [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) ;-)

```
#!/bin/bash
filesall=""
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
    do
        files=`echo "$1" | sed 's/ /\?/g'`
        filesall="$files $filesall"
        shift
    done
for i in $filesall; do mv "$i" "${i//[<>:\\|*\'\"?]/-}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Thunar (the XFCE file-manager) has a nice build in feature for bulk renaming of files. It has options for removing/replacing characters, search and replace, numbering files and more.

Install thunar:

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

Open thunar, browse to your files, select them and and choose 'rename' (via context menu or <kbd>F2</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. How many Characters Do You Want To Remove
echo.
echo. From The End Of The FileName ?
echo.
echo.
set /p variable=" > "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /b /a-d *.mp3') do (
set oldName=%%a
Set newName=!oldName:~0,-%variable%!.mp3
Ren "!oldName!" "!newName!"
)
exit
```

Comment: This works well and has a variable prompt  ... Name the file something like _ Truncate Last Characters.cmd

Comment: While this may be correct, this uses a Windows batch scripting language. We're on AskUbuntu, a site for Ubuntu related questions, and hence Ubuntu-related tools. My view is that this answer may not necessarily be appropriate here.

Comment: You'd need to run [it through Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104474/cmd-exe-emulator-in-ubuntu-to-run-cmd-bat-file) but it's probably possible to run this on Ubuntu... It's just a weird answer, tis all.