# How to rename a part of file using find command in directory and sub directories

Tags: command-line, find, rename

I have a lots of log file in a directory and it's sub directory named as `dataupload_sales_.xxx.com.dat`. I wanted to change all files `xxx.com` part to `yyy.com` in current and sub directories.

i hope it's not a duplicate post as i have search the forum and tried few option but none of them worked. some post suggested to use rename and it's only rename in single file. where i have 5000+ sub directories in my directory and every sub directories have 100+ `.dat` files.

i have also tried

```
find ./ -name "xxx.com" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 $(echo "$0" | sed -r \"s|xxx.com|yyy.com|g\")' '{}' \;
```

it shows invalid directory error

Comment: ..But also http://askubuntu.com/questions/406313/change-multiple-filenames-by-replacing-a-character and a few more...

Comment: find . -type f -exec rename 's/xxx/yyy/' {} \;  did the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From folder you want to change file names recursively:

```sh
find . -name '*.xxx.com.dat' -exec rename 's/xxx/yyy/' -- {} +
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, it will change files in sub directory's too.

Comment: supposed to do it