# How do I create a Windows XP Pro boot USB disk on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: 14.04, bootloader, windows-xp

How do I go about creating a boot disk, or any other type of disk that will allow me to get command prompt access, on Ubuntu for a Windows laptop?

It has to be USB, as the second laptop contains no CD drive. But I cant seem to figure out anywhere what it takes to create a bootable USB from Ubuntu that will work in a Windows environment (NTFS).

Comment: You're not very clear about what you want to achieve. You have two laptops, one with Ubuntu (U) and one with Windows XP (W). Do you want to access W from U? Do you want a bootable USB with full Windows on it, or only the command prompt? Will you use it on computer U or W?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I want is to be able to access the computer with Windows, via command line, as all the passwords are lost to access it. In order for me to do that, I need command line boot options. For that I need to create some startup disk. The other computer that has to do that is a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: OK, basically a lost Windows password problem. Have you seen this article on Wikihow? http://www.wikihow.com/Access-Your-Computer-if-You-Have-Forgotten-the-Password

Comment: Manipulating an external computer from within a Ubuntu one, is something I know very little about, but you may find something about that in this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/104474/cmd-exe-emulator-in-ubuntu-to-run-cmd-bat-file I would suggest trying the Wikihow steps first, though.

Comment: None of  the wiki would work. I am far beyond that. We are looking at having to access command prompt in order to change username and basically change some configuration in order to cheat around the password. What I need is "simple", a way to create a boot disk, on a USB, on a Ubuntu machine. How do I do that?

Comment: According to the following link, it can be done with Unetbootin. It shows how to create a Windows 7 USB, but I don't see why it shouldn't work for Windows XP Pro. You need the ISO file obviously, but how to get it, is a question for Superuser. http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Comment: NTFS is not visible on Unetbootin, but I worked around that.

Comment: Good if it worked in the end, might be a good idea to put the procedure in your own answer, to finish off the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix this!

Since Windows requires an NTFS bootable USB, it has to be created as such.

I installed http://gparted.org/ and formatted the USB as NTFS, and subsequently set a flag within Gparted to "boot", so that it can be treated as the boot drive.

After the USB is formatted, any ISO content can be moved to it.