# How to open a .bat file?

Tags: batch

The .bat file has this context "start client.exe ur;name=test;ip=79.114.123.26;port=8888"
Can anyone tell me the instuctions how to run it, thanks in advance

Comment: Try another OS. `.bat` files are used on Windows and also the command `start client.exe ...` shows that the file is intended to be used on Windows.

Comment: What is client.exe? What are you trying to achieve? What is _the real problem_?

Comment: It's possible to run **.bat** files in [Wine Console](http://askubuntu.com/a/54271/107450) but **.bat** files are not intended for Linux they are for Windows / DOS.  Perhaps you don't want to run this at all.  What are you trying to do?  It's always better to use a proper Linux tool where available.  What's the bigger picture here: Are you for example trying to get some particular hardware to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run .bat files, and also .exe files directly on linux. You can install wine program to use win applications.
Even if you run .bat file, the .bat file will not be able to run client.exe program.

wine installation:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wine winappname
```

The best way is writing a new bash script for linux.